# Context Menu disabled on webpage, how to re-enable it?

Tags: javascript, html

If a webpage has this:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

How can I restore the context menu functionality?

Comment: `document.body.oncontextmenu = null`

Comment: You the man @Endless